# Get shades of 6-digit hex color using CSS only?

Tags: css

I have an element with a box-shadow that has concentric layers with shades of a base colour. The colours are currently hard coded in.

Is there a clever hack to get shades of a 6-digit hex base colour using CSS only? i.e. without using JavaScript or CSS preprocessors?

I'm looking for something like:
`--layer-01: calc(var(--base-color) + 55)`
to set the opacity in this case.

```css
:root {
  --base-color: #1d5769;
  --layer-01: #c5ecf8;
  --layer-02: #d4f0f9;
  --layer-03: #e9f8fc;
  --layer-04: #f2fbfd;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--layer-01);
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 4px var(--layer-01), 
    0 0 0 6px var(--base-color), 
    0 0 0 46px var(--layer-02), 
    0 0 0 86px var(--layer-03), 
    0 0 0 126px var(--layer-04);
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```

Comment: No, this is not possible with **native CSS**. On second thoughts though you *could* use RGBA colors but that's 4 variables instead of 1.

Comment: _“I'm looking for something like: --layer-01: calc(var(--base-color) + 55) to set the opacity in this case.”_ - can you explain what value you expect the result of this to actually be then? Because you static example has `--layer-01: #c5ecf8;`, so where exactly does opacity come into play now?

Comment: @04FS I was looking at a way to concatenate the hex string (saved as `--base-color`) with two digits to form a new variable (`--layer-01`) as an 8-digit hex - giving it opacity. See here - https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/
So the expected value would have been #c5ecf855

Comment: Yeah, CSS doesn’t have a string concatenation mechanism anywhere outside of `content` as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

You can conside `hsl` colors and you will have better flexbility to control the `lightness` for example

```css
:root {
  --base-color:194, 57%;
  --layer-00: hsl(var(--base-color), 20%);
  --layer-01: hsl(var(--base-color), 40%);
  --layer-02: hsl(var(--base-color), 50%);
  --layer-03: hsl(var(--base-color), 60%);
  --layer-04: hsl(var(--base-color), 70%);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--layer-00);
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 4px var(--layer-01), 
    0 0 0 46px var(--layer-02), 
    0 0 0 86px var(--layer-03), 
    0 0 0 126px var(--layer-04);
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```

For opacity you can consider rgba syntax like below:

```css
:root {
  --base-color:29, 87, 105;
  --layer-00: rgba(var(--base-color), 1);
  --layer-01: rgba(var(--base-color), 0.8);
  --layer-02: rgba(var(--base-color), 0.6);
  --layer-03: rgba(var(--base-color), 0.4);
  --layer-04: rgba(var(--base-color), 0.2);
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: var(--layer-00);
  box-shadow: 
    0 0 0 4px var(--layer-01), 
    0 0 0 46px var(--layer-02), 
    0 0 0 86px var(--layer-03), 
    0 0 0 126px var(--layer-04);
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using a 6 digit hex string to set the base colour. I'm getting this from a custom colour picker. I have updated the question to reflect this. 
Your answer is useful non the less.

Comment: @JohanSwanepoel then it become more tricky. Even with the 8-digit it's not easy .. will try to think about another workaround ;)

Comment: _“I'm using a 6 digit hex string to set the base colour. I'm getting this from a custom colour picker”_ - still, should not be impossible to take that value from the custom color picker, split it into groups of two hex digits each, and then convert those to base10 …? It presumably doesn’t make its way into your CSS completely on its own, there’s got to be some programming language that would be capable of this basic operation involved somewhere, right?

Comment: @04FS Well yes, I'm currently using JavaScript to do the trick with `root.style.setProperty('--layer-01', root.style.getPropertyValue('--base-color') + '55');` where root is `document.documentElement`. I'm doing this for each of the 4 layers. The element is the initial loader and I'm trying to accommodate users with js disabled for whatever reason.

Comment: So why not do this on the server side already? (I assume you are not talking about something that has to happen live on the client side here? Without JS there is probably not much date-picking going on to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) property, though it applies to the whole element. Applying it to :pseudo allows to hack 2 of the 5 layers: **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ywNoqZ?editors=0100)**.

```css
:root {
  --base-color: #1d5769;
  --layer-01: #c5ecf8;
  --layer-02: #d4f0f9;
  /*--layer-03: #e9f8fc;
  --layer-04: #f2fbfd;*/
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 5rem;
  margin: 10rem;
  background-color: var(--layer-01);
  box-shadow:
    0 0 0 4px var(--layer-01),
    0 0 0 6px var(--base-color),
    0 0 0 46px var(--layer-02);/*,
    0 0 0 86px var(--layer-03),
    0 0 0 126px var(--layer-04);*/
}

.box::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -126px;
  left: -126px;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 252px);
  height: calc(100% + 252px);
  border: 40px solid var(--base-color);
  filter: brightness(800%);
}

.box::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -86px;
  left: -86px;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 172px);
  height: calc(100% + 172px);
  border: 40px solid var(--base-color);
  filter: brightness(700%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

So here you'd need an extra empty element which would bring 3 more stylable areas…

Maybe a custom PNG(.SVG?) [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) would do the trick? Or hum final idea **replace your `box-shadow` by an SVG made of 5 surimposed rectangles**. Their `fill` color would be your picked color and 4 of them have a brightness filter.

Probably good ideas in [Learn About CSS Custom Properties Through Clever Uses of Them](https://dev.to/chriscoyier/learn-about-css-custom-properties-through-clever-uses-of-them-2fjo) (Chris Coyer) and its link to DRY switching or if you can have `--picked: 240, 127, 172;` then [Theming with CSS variables in RGBA](https://codepen.io/finnhvman/post/theming-with-css-variables-in-rgba) (Ben Szabo) should do the trick.